# Turning weekly to monthly data in Python dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to turn this dictionary:

```
dic = {'2007-10-21': '53', '2007-10-28': '50', '2007-11-05': '100','2007-11-06': '99'}
```

Into something like this:

```
dic = {'2007-10': '103', '2007-11': '199'}
```

Since I need to do that in scale, pythonly speaking I need to sum all the values which its keys start with the same 7 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
__author__ = 'Fawzan'

dic = {'2007-10-21': '53', '2007-10-28': '50', '2007-11-05': '100', '2007-11-06': '99'}

# create a new dictionary

newDic = {}

# iterate the old dictionary

for key in dic:

# get the desiresd string for comparision
k = key[0:7]

# for debug
print(k)

# if the key is already in the new dictionary, then add the value to existing key
if (k in newDic):
    newDic[k] += float(dic[key])

# else append the key, value
else:
    newDic[k] = float(dic[key])

# print and check the answer :)

print(newDic)
```

Comment: Thanks Fawzan! It works fine for ints, however I might have floats in the dictionary. Any idea how to adapt?

Comment: Yep, you can simply cast it to a float instead of int :)

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I modified the code, Please consider accepting & upvote if it worked. :)

Comment: Sure, I'm new to stackflow, let me just figure how to do it